# Как мне вывести любую надпись с помощью массива?

Tags: java

```java
package names.gen;

import java.util.Random;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class names {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String [] names = new String[]{"Шепард","Геральт из Ривии", "Лара Крофт", "Кратос", "Гордон Фримен", "Бэтмен", "Данте", "Марио", "Цири", "Букер Девитт"};
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.print("Как Вас бы звали в мире игр? Нажмите 1 чтобы продолжить: ");
        int next = scanner.nextInt();

        Random random = new Random();
        int randomNames = random.nextInt(names.length);
        switch (names.length){
            case names[0]:
        }

        System.out.println(names[randomNames]);

    }
}
```

Мне нужно чтобы моя программа рандомила массив и при выводе любого имени выводила еще и текст с описанием самого персонажа. Я пытался сделать это через switch and if, но ничего так и не смог придумать.

Answer (score 3):

Самый очевидный способ, пожалуй - это вместо массива строк сделать массив кортежей (имя, описание), потом сгенерировать случайное число, сохранить его в переменную и выводить соответственно не просто массив[рандом], а массив[сохранённый_рандом][имя], массив[сохранённый_рандом][описание].

Второй вариант (проще, но "грязнее") - сделать два массива одинаковой длины, и в первый записать имена, а во второй - описания в том же порядке, в каком идут имена. Потом сгенерировать случайное число, сохранить это число в переменную, и выводить соответствующие элементы обоих массивов: массив_имён[сохранённый_рандом], массив_описаний[сохранённый_рандом].